# How to get the value of JSP variable inside Script function?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to show the value of a variable with an alert message, I wrote this code in a jsp page,

```
<c:set var="my_var" value="Hello world!"/>
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        alert("<%=my_var%>");
        return false;
        }
</script>
```

But when I run it I get this error

> cannot resolve symbol symbol  : variable my_var

plz help me with any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scripting variable is not a scoped variable.  Try using

alert("${my_var}");

Comment: tried but the alert message shows **${my_var}** instead of **Hello world!**

Comment: It works for me. Did you substitute my code line into the code you posted?  Please perform a test with a JSP having only the content of ${"Hello from JSP2"}   . If that doesn't print just Hello from JSP2  when you browse to it,   then your configuration is wrong. What web server are you using? Tomcat? Which version?